# What is the usage of Angular directive novalidate in a form html tag

Tags: html, validation, forms

I wanted to understand the meaning of novalidate directive usage in form tag, especially when used to validate the form.

Thanks

Answer (score 82, accepted):

It prevents the browser's native validation to kick in i.e form data will not be validated upon submission. Examples include input where `type='email'`

Note that it is not Angular's directive. It is HTML 5 attribute. Read more about it [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_novalidate.asp)

Answer (score 17):

**novalidate** attribute is used to disable browser's native form validation.

You can use it when you need do your own AngularJS custom validation.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the same ones used by the HTML 5 specification in Angular,so you can add the **novalidate** attribute to the *form* element, which tells the browser **not** to use its **native validation**. Because different browsers have different implementation validations. Since Angular get validation itself, the browser don't need to do validation implementation.